# I populate a list<string> with linq, but the order of the items is random

Tags: linq

I have this linq syntax

```
var jsonData = new
            {
                total = 1,
                page = 1,
                records = per.Count(),
                rows = 
                           from r in per
                           select new
                           {
                               id = r.id,
                               cell = new List<string>()
                                  {
                                       SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)  r.id),
                                       r.nombre,
                                       r.mail,
                                       r.documento
                                  }
                           }
            };
```

The problem is that the value of each list in cell property has random order of items.

Example result:

```
        item 1:  id:"         1"    string
        nombre:"Medina Teto"    string
        mail: "soyelteto@hotmail.com"   string
        dni:"DNI 12312322"  string
    item 2:
            dni:"DNI 12312872"  string
            mail:"elancho@hotmail.com"  string
            nombre: "Peuchele Ruben"    string
            id: "         2"    string

        item 3:
            id: "         3"    string
            nombre: "la momia Blanca"   string
            mail: "soylamomiabuena@hotmail.com" string
            dni: "DNI 45612322" string
```

The item 2 has first dni and then mail. the other items has first id and then name

why happend this?

Comment: You should anonymize your code

Comment: This post is *really* hard to read - trying to work out the contents of each element from you debugger dump is a nightmare. Please reformat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
 var rows = per.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(r => new
                           {
                               id = r.id,
                               cell = new[]
                                  {
                                       r.id.ToString(),
                                       r.nombre,
                                       r.mail,
                                       r.documento
                                  }
                           }).ToArray();

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = 1,
                page = 1,
                records = per.Count(),
                rows
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it happens (although I think that the enumeration order of items in a `List<T>` is not guaranteed to be stable), but it can be solved by using named values:

```
cell = new
{
    dni = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)  r.id),
    nombre = r.nombre,
    mail = r.mail,
    documento = r.documento
}
```

Additional benefit: the receiving side knows better what it's dealing with.

---

**EDIT** (after your comment)

Try your luck with

```
cell = new SortedList<int,string>
{
    { 1, r.id.ToString() },
    { 2, r.nombre },
    { 3, r.mail },
    { 4, r.documento }
}
```

But you'll have to convert to `IEnumerable` first, EF does not support list initializers with multiple elements.

Comment: I need that the values were a list of strings, to populate jqgrid.

Comment: To convert it to IENUMERABLE  i have to go through each item and manually generate a new list?

Comment: It would be enough to do `from r in per.AsEnumerable`, but I don't know if you fetch too much data in memory then.

Comment: Thanks, so i have this code. 
from r in per.AsEnumerable()
                               select new
                               {
                                   id = r.id,
                                   cell = new List<string>()
                                      {...
                                           .mail,
                                           r.documento
                                      }
                               }
but now i get this error: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

Comment: Ah yes, of course. But good news: you're in linq-to-objects now, so you can use standard .Net (`ToString()`).

Comment: Where i have to put .tostring()?

Comment: Now i have this error throwing in the view when it tries to serialize to json. Only list initializer items with a single element are supported in LINQ to Entities.